# Break string into words using scan method + regexp, if word has `'` character, drop this character and everything after it

Tags: regex, ruby, parsing

```
sample_string = "let's could've they'll you're won't"
sample_string.scan(/\w+/)
```

Above gives me:

```
["let", "s", "could", "ve", "they", "ll", "you", "re", "won", "t"]
```

What I want:

```
["let", "could", "they", "you", "won"]
```

Been playing around in https://rubular.com/ and trying assertions like `\w+(?<=')` but no luck.

Comment: A tiny point: some English words, such as "shouldn't've" have [double apostrophes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_double_contractions). Some even have [triple contractions](https://www.wordnik.com/lists/triple-contractions). I presume you are not concerned about dealing with those.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up, you are right with that assumption. In case I would have to deal with double/tripple apostrophes, instead of dropping characters, I may as well expand on them to get words without apostrophes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```rb
sample_string.scan(/(?<![\w'])\w+/)
sample_string.scan(/\b(?<!')\w+/)
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/Vfxj6oT927TAva). The patterns (they are absolute synonyms) match

- `(?<![\w'])` - a location in the string that is not immediately preceded with a word or `'` char
- `\b(?<!')` - a word boundary position which is not immediately preceded with a `'` char
- `\w+` - one or more word chars.

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/3BMaFP):

```rb
sample_string = "let's could've they'll you're won't"
p sample_string.scan(/(?<![\w'])\w+/)
# => ["let", "could", "they", "you", "won"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
> sample_string = "let's could've they'll you're won't"
```

You can do split and map:

```
> sample_string.split.map{|w| w.split(/'/)[0]}
=> ["let", "could", "they", "you", "won"]
```